# how to throw customize fault message from jax-rs webservice

Tags: jax-rs, soapfault

Can any one help me out how i can throw a customize server exception from jax-rs webservice which will be send response to client in the  xml tag. as  I am not be able to find the wsdl file for that webservice so can any one help me out by providing complete tutorial or  complete example

Thanks In Advance.